# "Cannot call method 'transaction' of undefined" error in indexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Below is my code. It runs fine for the first time but once I refresh the page it generates an uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'transaction' of undefined.

Basically I retrieve from data from a database and encode it into a usable JSON datatype to avoid insert issues into my tables.

```
$(document).ready( function() {

//prefixes of implementation that we want to test
window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB ||
                   window.mozIndexedDB ||
                   window.webkitIndexedDB ||
                   window.msIndexedDB;

//prefixes of window.IDB objects
window.IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction ||
                        window.webkitIDBTransaction ||
                        window.msIDBTransaction;

window.IDBKeyRange = window.IDBKeyRange ||
                     window.webkitIDBKeyRange ||
                     window.msIDBKeyRange

if(!window.indexedDB){ //alert user if browser does not support
    window.alert("Your browser doesn't support a stable version of IndexedDB.")
}

var request = window.indexedDB.open("runningClub", 1); //create a runningClub database

var browserDB;

request.onsuccess = function(event){
    browserDB = request.result;
};

var raceIDs = [];

$(".raceID").each( function () {
    raceIDs.push(" raceID = " + $(this).val());
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'controller/AJAX/userAction.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { statement : "getRaceResult", raceIDs : raceIDs },
    success: function(data) {

        const results = data;

        request.onupgradeneeded = function(event){
            var browserDB = event.target.result;
            var objectStore = browserDB.createObjectStore("raceResult", {keyPath: "resultID"});
            for(var i in results){
                objectStore.add(results[i]);       
            }
        }

        var objectStore = browserDB.transaction("raceResult").objectStore("raceResult");

        objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event){
            var cursor = event.target.result;
            if (cursor){
                $("#memberName").append("<option>" + cursor.value.memberName + "</option>");
                cursor.continue();
            }
        };
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for posting the (almost) entirety of your code. Unfortunately I can't fully replicate your issue without knowing the structure of the data object coming from your backend. Mind publishing that as well?

That said, I'm rather certain your issue is the use of `const`.

```
const results = data;
```

I do not believe this type of data to be "[structured clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/The_structured_clone_algorithm)"-able. Given that JSON is fully clonable, which is what I imagine to be returned from your API (vs. e.g. JavaScript that could be evaulated to produce a `function`), the usage of this keyword seems the likely culprit of your issues.

**Update 1** Working through this, quite a few issues with your async programming.

- database is opened before ajax request, rather than after successful callback. seems prudent to move this into the callback.
- `browserDB` is defined in a `success` callback that isn't guaranteed to run before the async operation completes (thus `browserDB` becomes undefined)
- `request.onsuccess` is called twice (you may not have realized this, because it's weird behavior): both when no `upgradeneeded` event fires and when an `upgradeneeded` event fires, so you're redefining `browserDB` perhaps accidentally when the DB doesn't yet exist

**Update 2** Here's a mostly working, [simplified Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taylorbuley/B7AGF/). I'm sad at how much time I spent making your code work.

More issues (beyond `const`):

- hardcoded database version
- reusing `versionchange` event for adding/getting data is a bad idea
- need to use a `readwrite` transaction to add data
- openCursor - but don't supply parameters for resultID keypath
- you are not listening for successful adds before getting the data
- you are not chaining your success events for adds before getting the data

The current loop approach was untenable. But I got it working with a single add and a cursor get. You can refactor back into a multiple-add approach but you'll need to watch your async (based on what I see, I'd suggest you stick with simple).

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/echo/json/',
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    json: JSON.stringify({
      resultID: new Date().getTime(),
      raceID: "1",
      memberID: "824",
      runtime: "00:31:26",
      memberName‌: "Mark Hudspith"
    })
  },
  success: function (data) {
    var request,
      upgrade = false,
      doTx = function (db, entry) {
        addData(db, entry, function () {
          getData(db);
        });
      },
      getData = function (db) {
        db.transaction(["raceResult"], "readonly").objectStore("raceResult").openCursor(IDBKeyRange.lowerBound("0")).onsuccess = function (event) {
          var cursor = event.target.result;
          if (null !== cursor) {
            console.log("YOUR DATA IS HERE", cursor.value.memberName‌);
            cursor.continue();
          }
        };
      },
      addData = function (db, entry, finished) {
        var tx = db.transaction(["raceResult"], "readwrite");
        tx.addEventListener('complete', function (e) {
          finished();
        });
        tx.objectStore("raceResult").add(entry);
      };
    request = window.indexedDB.open("runningClub");
    request.onsuccess = function (event) {
      if (!upgrade) {
        doTx(request.result, data);
      }
    };
    request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
      var db = event.target.result;
      db.createObjectStore("raceResult", {
        keyPath: "resultID"
      });
      setTimeout(function () {
        doTx(db, data);
      }, 5000);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: the backend is somethign like this : 
case 'getRaceResult':
  
  $raceResults = $user->getAllRaceResult($raceIDs);
  
  echo json_encode($raceResults);
  
  break;

Comment: Paste failed, but remove the "const" keyword, replace with `var`, and give it a shot for me.

Comment: PHP, cool, I'm totally following - but I'd need the value of `$raceResults`. What I'm looking to do is confirm your data is storable. IDB can't store all types of JavaScript data.

Comment: one of the return data is : [{"resultID":"1","raceID":"1","memberID":"824","runtime":"00:31:26","memberName":"Mark Hudspith"}]

Comment: Updated my answer using this data. This was a really, really messy async knot to untangle.

Comment: Thanks for your effort